# Jquery chkbox show hidden content?

Tags: jquery

I want to create multiplay chkbox, when I select to show hidden div, its work with this one, but how to count automatically, if I have more chkbox?

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    //Hide div w/id extra
   $("#extra").css("display","none");

    // Add onclick handler to checkbox w/id checkme
   $("#checkme").click(function(){

    // If checked
    if ($("#checkme").is(":checked"))
    {
        //show the hidden div
        $("#extra").show("fast");
    }
    else
    {
        //otherwise, hide it
        $("#extra").hide("fast");
    }
  });

});


<form action="" method="get"> <input name="" type="checkbox" value="" id="checkme"> <span> $1 + </span> </form>
  <div id="extra" style="width:10px; height:10px; background-color:#000;"> 123 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try defining a `<div id="container">` and using

```
$("#container :checkbox:not(:checked)").size()
```